# Parse Verizon PDF Bill Call Log

Tags: python, string, bash, powershell, parsing

I extracted the talk activity contents of my Verizon bill to a text file. I want to do some analysis of the data. I prefer using powershell, python or bash.  Any ideas on how I can convert the following to a csv:

> Jan 6 12:30 PM Unavailable Las Vegas, NV Incoming, CL 2
>
> Jan 7 11:06 AM 697.732.5672 Reno, NV Victorvl, CA 30
>
> Jan 4 3:26 PM 702.792.2189 Las Vegas, NV VM Deposit, CL 1
>
> Jan 24 4:24 PM 213.302.2581 Sacramento, CA Incoming, CL 105

Example of what the results should look like:

> "Jan 6 12:30 PM","Unavailable","Las Vegas, NV","Incoming, CL","2"
>
> "Jan 7 11:06 AM","697.732.5672","Reno, NV","Victorvl, CA","30"
>
> "Jan 4 3:26 PM","702.792.2189","Las Vegas, NV","VM Deposit, CL","1"
>
> "Jan 24 4:24 PM","213.302.2581","Sacramento, CA","Incoming, CL","105"

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: You want to "convert the following"? What type of data is the "following" exactly? Same issue with desired results...

Comment: The data is just text in a text file. I thought at first it was fixed width but it isn't. Looking at this some more I believe regex is the only solution.

Comment: The closure of your question notwithstanding (which I don't agree with, since the question was clear enough, even though no problem-solving effort was demonstrated), I think you've received good answers here, so I encourage you to accept the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hesitant to just post an answer here, as the problem space isn't clearly defined, and there isn't any work included to show where you're getting stuck, or if you've tried anything at all.

On the other hand, it's an opportunity to highlight some basic string parsing tactics in Python, so I'm going to treat this as a kind of annotated walkthrough that may be of some benefit to people who land on this post.

The approach I'm taking is to split each content line into space-separated elements, and then combine the appropriate pieces.

Let's assume the input `data` look exactly as posted, with lines of whitespace separating lines of content.  Then `data.split("\n")` will yield a 7-element list: 4 lines with content and three empty string (`''`) lines:

```
data.split("\n")

['Jan 6 12:30 PM Unavailable Las Vegas, NV Incoming, CL 2',
 '',
 'Jan 7 11:06 AM 697.732.5672 Reno, NV Victorvl, CA 30',
 '',
 'Jan 4 3:26 PM 702.792.2189 Las Vegas, NV VM Deposit, CL 1',
 '',
 'Jan 24 4:24 PM 213.302.2581 Sacramento, CA Incoming, CL 105']
```

We can drop the empty string lines by checking for `len(x)` (which will evaluate to `False` if `len == 0`), and then `split()` the remaining lines by single spaces.

```
lines = [x.split() for x in data.split("\n") if len(x)]

lines
[['Jan', '6', '12:30', 'PM', 'Unavailable', 'Las', 'Vegas,', 'NV', 'Incoming,', 'CL', '2'],  
 ['Jan', '7', '11:06', 'AM', '697.732.5672', 'Reno,', 'NV', 'Victorvl,', 'CA', '30'],  
 ['Jan', '4', '3:26', 'PM', '702.792.2189', 'Las', 'Vegas,', 'NV', 'VM', 'Deposit,', 'CL', '1'],  
 ['Jan', '24', '4:24', 'PM', '213.302.2581', 'Sacramento,', 'CA', 'Incoming,', 'CL', '105']]
```

I'm going to assume that three fields in each record always have the same number of elements: the date/time, the IP address, and the final number (call duration?).  That makes it easy to hard code the number of elements that we should `join()` for those fields.

The problematic fields are the location fields, as the number of string chunks may vary for each location.  For example, `"Reno, NV"` becomes a 2-element list (`["Reno,", "NV"]`) after our splitting operation above.  But `"Las Vegas, NV"` becomes `["Las", "Vegas,", "NV"]` after the `split`, with 3 elements.  That means we can't just hard code the start and end index of each set of location strings to use in `join`.

One hack we can use here is to add a special character to the last string of a set of location strings.  Then we can just `join` all of the two location fields together initially, and `split` on the special character afterwards.  It's a little inelegant, but it will get the job done.

How to figure out which string chunk is the last one in a set of location strings?  It seems safe to assume that if one string chunk ends in a comma (e.g. `'Vegas,'` or `'Reno,'`), then the next chunk is going to be the state abbreviation, which is the last one in that location set.  We can add a `*` marker to the chunk after the "comma chunk", like this:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(line):     
    if elem[-1] == ",":
        line[i+1] += "*"
```

Then, after we've performed a `join` on both location string sets (which are adjacent in the raw data), we can do another split on `*` to separate them.

Here's the full solution:

```
lines = [x.split() for x in data.split("\n") if len(x)]
grouped = []

for line in lines:
    for i, elem in enumerate(line):
        if elem[-1] == ",":
            line[i+1] += "*"
    grp = [' '.join([str(x) for x in line[:4]]), 
           str(line[4]), 
           ' '.join([str(x) for x in line[5:]])]
    grouped.append(grp[:2] + grp[2].split("* "))
```

Output:

```
grouped

[['Jan 6 12:30 PM', 'Unavailable', 'Las Vegas, NV', 'Incoming, CL', '2'],
 ['Jan 7 11:06 AM', '697.732.5672', 'Reno, NV', 'Victorvl, CA', '30'],
 ['Jan 4 3:26 PM', '702.792.2189', 'Las Vegas, NV', 'VM Deposit, CL', '1'],
 ['Jan 24 4:24 PM', '213.302.2581', 'Sacramento, CA', 'Incoming, CL', '105']]
```

You can store that as a CSV, using whatever I/O methods you prefer.
(IMO, Pandas makes it easy: `pd.DataFrame(grouped).to_csv("records.csv", index=False)`)

Answer (score 1):

This code breaks the record down with a regex, creates a new object, then exports it to a CSV file.

```
[regex]$rx = '(?<ts>\S+\s\S+\s\S+\s\S+)\s+(?<number>\S+)\s+(?<citystate>[^,]*,\s\S{2})\s+(?<direction>[^,]*, \S{2})\s+(?<minutes>\d*)'

Get-Content -Path '.\phonebill.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $m = $rx.Match($_)

        $record = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
            Timestamp = $m.groups['ts'].Value
            Number = $m.groups['number'].Value
            CityState = $m.groups['citystate'].Value
            Direction = $m.groups['direction'].Value
            Minutes = $m.groups['minutes'].Value
        }

        $record | Export-Csv -Path '.\phonebill.csv' -Append -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

It produces the following output.

```
"Timestamp","Number","CityState","Direction","Minutes"
"Jan 6 12:30 PM","Unavailable","Las Vegas, NV","Incoming, CL","2"
"Jan 7 11:06 AM","697.732.5672","Reno, NV","Victorvl, CA","30"
"Jan 4 3:26 PM","702.792.2189","Las Vegas, NV","VM Deposit, CL","1"
"Jan 24 4:24 PM","213.302.2581","Sacramento, CA","Incoming, CL","105"
```

Revised following @TheMadTechnician's and @mklement0's good suggestions.

```
[regex]$rx = '(?<ts>\S+\s\S+\s\S+\s\S+)\s+(?<number>\S+)\s+(?<citystate>[^,]*,\s\S{2})\s+(?<direction>[^,]*, \S{2})\s+(?<minutes>\d*)'

Get-Content -Path '.\phonebill.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match $rx) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Timestamp = $Matches.ts
                Number = $Matches.number
                CityState = $Matches.citystate
                Direction = $Matches.direction
                Minutes = $Matches.minutes
            }
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path '.\phonebill.csv' -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Get a real `[datetime]` object for the timestamp with `Timestamp = [datetime]::ParseExact($m.groups['ts'].Value,'MMM d hh:mm tt',$null)`. That way if you want to search for calls between 9PM and 6AM (was little Jonny up all night talking on the phone to his girlfriend?), you can do actual date or time comparisons. Also, skip the `$record = ` and `$record | Export-Csv` lines, and send the objects down the pipeline directly. Output to CSV at the end if desired, or capture the data in a variable.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - A real datetime type would be helpful during the analysis. The stated OP goal was to produce a CSV file. That might be taken into a spreadsheet, or PowerShell, or something else for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some python which should do that, the RE should be transferable to several other languages:

```
import re

with open('gash.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(r"(.+[AP]M) ((?:Unavailable)|(?:[0-9\.]+)) ([\w ]+?, [A-Z]{2}) ([\w ]+?, [A-Z]{2}) (\d+)" ,line)
        if m:
            val = '"'+'","'.join(m.groups())+'"'
            print(val)
```

Gives:

```
"Jan 6 12:30 PM","Unavailable","Las Vegas, NV","Incoming, CL","2"
"Jan 7 11:06 AM","697.732.5672","Reno, NV","Victorvl, CA","30"
"Jan 4 3:26 PM","702.792.2189","Las Vegas, NV","VM Deposit, CL","1"
"Jan 24 4:24 PM","213.302.2581","Sacramento, CA","Incoming, CL","105"
```

Please ask if you need any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your data is that the input lines have a *variable* number of tokens in the location fields (e.g., `Reno, NV` vs. `Las Vegas, NV`), which, in the absence of field delimiters rules out breaking the lines into fields purely by indices.

Here's a pragmatic PowerShell solution that:

- starts with whitespace-based splitting and extracts the fields whose token count and position *doesn't* vary by line.
- breaks the remaining tokens into the two location fields by the `, <state-abbreviation>` suffix they each have, via a regular expression:

<sup>Note: I'm assuming that the empty lines between the data lines (and also the output lines) are an artifact of posting your question. If they are in the actual input, add `if (-not $_) { return }` as the 1st line of the `Foreach-Object` block below to ignore them.</sup>

```
& {
  # Output the CSV header row.
  '"Date","Number","Loc1","Loc2","Duration"'
  # Process the input lines and generate the output CSV rows.
  Get-Content call-log.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $tokens = -split $_ # split line into tokens by whitespace
    $date = $tokens[0..3] -join ' ' # first 4 tokens
    $number = $tokens[4] # 5th token
    $duration = $tokens[-1] # last token
    # split the remaining tokens into thw two locations by inserting
    # a '|' char. after the first ', <state-abbrev>' and then splitting by it.
    $loc1, $loc2 =
      $tokens[5..($tokens.Count-2)] -join ' ' -replace '(, [A-Z]{2}) ', '$1|' -split '\|'
    # Synthesize and output the CSV data row.
    '"{0}","{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}"' -f $date, $number, $loc1, $loc2, $duration
  } 
} | Set-Content out.csv
```

Note that the output file's character encoding will be "ANSI" (the encoding implied by the legacy code page associated with your system locale) in Windows PowerShell (in PowerShell Core it would be UTF-8 without BOM); use `Set-Content`'s `-Encoding` parameter to change that.